# Bootstrap Modal not closing in Safari

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari, bootstrap-modal

I have an issue with bootstrap where Modals are not closing upon form submission in Safari but it is fine in Chrome. Note this is a Django project but I don't think that is the issue.

Also I am using using this upload progress bar for the uploads but I am getting the issue both with this and without.

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>VideoOrganiser</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    {% load static %}

    <link href="{% static 'mfo/base_style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="{% static 'scripts/index.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'scripts/bootstrap-uploadprogress.js' %}" type="text/javascript"> </script>

</head>
<body data-spy="spyscroll">
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/" style="font-size: 200%">VideoOrganiser</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li style="padding-top: 11px">
                    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload Media</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Media</h4>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ upload_form }}
                <input type="submit" id="upload_submit" style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-default" value="Upload" />
            </form>
            <script>
                $("#upload_form").uploadprogress({redirect_url: "/"})
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron" id="file_system_jumbo"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the rendered HTML from Safari

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>VideoOrganiser</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <link href="/static/mfo/base_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="/static/scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/scripts/bootstrap-uploadprogress.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

</head>
<body data-spy="spyscroll">
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/" style="font-size: 200%">VideoOrganiser</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li style="padding-top: 11px">
                    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload Media</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Media</h4>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="N9n4G7teXfsWt8qXue6S9hOja0I2lLzhe61qPs6OXpZQxX5vYSOVL0LQLDYMuO5a">
                <label for="id_uploaded_file">Uploaded file:</label><input id="id_uploaded_file" name="uploaded_file" type="file" required="">
                <input type="submit" id="upload_submit" style="margin-top: 10px" class="btn btn-default" value="Upload">
            </form>
            <script>
                $("#upload_form").uploadprogress({redirect_url: "/"})
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron" id="file_system_jumbo"><p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>/Users/ryanrushton/Movies</p><ul class="list-group" id="file_system_list"><li class="list-group-item"><p><a onclick="get_file_system('/Users/ryanrushton/Movies/Movies');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>Movies</a></p></li><li class="list-group-item"><p><a onclick="get_file_system('/Users/ryanrushton/Movies/TV Shows');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>TV Shows</a></p></li></ul></div>
</div></body></html>
```

Cheers for the help!

Edit: Removed views.py and added rendered HTML as requested.

Comment: I'm agree, tt seems to be an html/css/js error. Why are you providing us your django code ? Please, provide us HTML rendered code. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: Edited as requested!

Comment: Look in Chrome console for errors, and provide them here

Comment: Which versions of Safari and OS are you using ?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I'm using latest OSX and latest safari.